# How can the CALayerGradient conic be rendered?

Tags: ios, swift, gradient

I'm trying to render a conic gradient using CALayerGradient in a CGContext

```
    let colors = [ UIColor(hue: 0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                   UIColor(hue: 1/6, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                   UIColor(hue: 2/6, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                   UIColor(hue: 0.5, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                    UIColor(hue: 4/6, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                    UIColor(hue: 5/6, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                    UIColor(hue: 1.0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor ]

    let conicGradient = CAGradientLayer()
    conicGradient.type = .conic
    conicGradient.frame = bounds
    conicGradient.startPoint = CGPoint( x: 0.5, y: 0.5 )
    conicGradient.endPoint = CGPoint( x: 1, y: 1 )
    conicGradient.colors = colors as [Any]

    conicGradient.render( in: mContext ) // This doesn't work

    if let drawingContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    {
        drawingContext.draw( myContext.makeImage()!, in: bounds )
    }
```

Above, changing type to anything else will work.
Also, if i don't try rendering to CGContext, but add this as a sublayer, it works, the only thing that doesn't work, is the conic rendered in a CGContext, which is the thing i want to do.
So is there something i'm missing, or is the rendering of conic not implemented ?

Comment: What is `mContext`? Define "doesn't work". Never use those words without fully explaining in what way exactly that the code doesn't work.

Comment: mContext is the CGContext i'm trying to render in. By doesn't work, i mean there are no pixel drawn, only a clear image, unlike the other ones, that do render the pixels as intended.

Comment: My objective is to render the gradient in a "buffer" CGContext : mContext, and then eventually render it to screen in the draw function. Hopes this clarify my objectives

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to render into an arbitrary context, try pushing that context using `UIGraphicsPushContext(_:)`, drawing into the now-current context, and then popping that context off with  `UIGraphicsPopContext()`.

Comment: I tried it, but as i'm not familiar with UIKit at all, i probably did it wrong. What i did in the draw function of my IUView : `UIGraphicsPushContext( mContext )` followed by `myConicGradient.render( in: mContext )` and then `UIGraphicsPopContext()`. I finally got the new current render context : `if let drawingContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` and drew my context in it `drawingContext.draw( mContext, in: bounds )` to draw it to screen. The result was still a clear image